# Python keylogger with keystroke durations

Tags: keystroke, keylogger

I was searching a program which detects my keystrokes with the stoke's duration also. I imagine the output like this: 
W : 3 sec
A : 2.4 sec 
etc..
Can someone help me how to create a program like this in python? I couldn't even start it.

Comment: Have you looked at this three-part series on YouTube? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tBkieuXY1Ik
Alternatively, there are plenty of other keylogger tutorials on YouTube.

Comment: I saw tons of keyloggers like this, but they can't show the durations of the keystokes